# How to get bean from context in jUnit of EJB?

Tags: java, junit, ejb

I'm trying to create tests (for laboratories) of EJB controller DB objects. My problem is with creating a lookup to context during initiation:
`javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "global/Lab45r-ejb/BookBean!pl.polsl.lab45r.book.BookBean" not found.`
I'm using Java with Maven project.
Initiation code:

```
public class BaseScenarioTest {

    private static EJBContainer container;
    private static BookBean bookBean;
    private static LibraryBean libraryBean;

    private static BookTest bookTest;
    private static LibraryTest libraryTest;

    private Integer bookId;
    private Integer libraryId;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initOnce() throws NamingException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("xyz", "new://Resource?type=DataSource");
        // These properties (UserName, Password, JdbcUrl) should point
        // to your database
        properties.put("xyz.UserName", "root");
        properties.put("xyz.Password", "root");
        properties.put("xyz.JdbcUrl",
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lab");
        properties.put("xyz.JdbcDriver", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        properties.put("xyz.JtaManaged", "true");
        properties.put("xyz.ConnectionProperties",
                "useSSL=false;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true");
        container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(properties);
        bookBean = (BookBean) container.getContext().lookup("java:global/Lab45R-ejb/BookBean"); //<-- here it fails
        libraryBean = (LibraryBean) container.getContext().lookup("java:global/Lab45R-ejb/LibraryBean");

        libraryTest = new LibraryTest();
        bookTest = new BookTest();
    }

...
```

I was trying to change `java:global/Lab45r-ejb/BookBean` into `java:global/Lab45r-ejb/BookBean!package.lab45r.book.BookBean` and LibraryBean simultaneously, as both beans are in the different packages than "Scenario" package.

Error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "global/Lab45R-ejb/BookBean" not found.
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.federate(IvmContext.java:199)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:151)
    at org.apache.xbean.naming.context.ContextFlyweight.lookup(ContextFlyweight.java:55)
    at package.lab45r.scenario.BaseScenario.initOnce(BaseScenario.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

-I have also one additional problem, that this test doesn't start automatically when building application.- - this I fixed by changing name of the class.

Comment: I would try with "java:global/classes/LibraryBean". I have something similar that works.

Comment: Thanks, anyway my problem was caused by missed capital letters if I remember correctly ;)